# How does the improved Exp. Share work?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

In older generations, Exp.Share was a held item which gave a share of Exp. to the Pokemon holding it. Now, it is a key item which "will allow all the Pokemon on your team to receive Exp. Points from battles."

How exactly does this work? Do Pokemon who actually participated still get more Exp? Does the total amount your team earns remain constant regardless of how many Pokemon in it?

Comment: ALright, I have another question but I dont think its worth making another page, where does find the EXP Share in X and Y?

Comment: You can ask that separately but you get it right after beating the first gym leader but before heading to route 3(?) I believe. Whatever the route right after the first Gym is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The participating Pokemon only get experience once. Everybody else in the party gets half of the total each.

Experience gain is independent of participants and number of Pokemon in your party, so yes, your party gains more experience overall if you have more people in your party at the same time.

All pokemon earn experience independently. So the rest of your party does not affect the amount of experience they earn. This is also independent of the Exp. Share's on-state.

I do not know how EV's through Battle work in Gen 6. So I won't comment on their distribution here.

So five example Pancham Battles:

Battle 1a (4 party members):

- Pokemon A participates.
- Pokemon A earned 80 experience.
- Pokemon B,C and D earn 40 experience each.

Battle 1b (3 Party Members):

- Pokemon A participates.
- Pokemon A earned 80 experience.
- Pokemon B and C earn 40 experience each.

Battle Example 2a (Exp. Share On):

- Pokemon A and B participate.
- Pokemon A and B get 80 experience each.
- Pokemon C and D earn 40 experience each.

Battle Example 2b (Exp. Share Off):

- Pokemon A and B participate.
- Pokemon A and B get 80 experience each.
- Pokemon C and D get 0 experience each.

Battle Example 2c (3 party Member Exp. Share Off):

- Pokemon A participates.
- Pokemon A gets 80 experience each.
- Pokemon B and C get 0 experience each.

Traded Pokemon do get boosted experience even if they do not participate.

Comment: So there's zero detriment to having it turned on, or having a full party?

Comment: As far as I can tell. I forgot to check with it turned off.

Comment: These examples aren't very helpful for illustrating, because you keep changing the number of pokemon and the total amount of experience distributed among them. Can you please give examples with the same total number of pokemon and the same total experience, divided up based on who participated?

Comment: The examples point out that the amount of experience is not related to the number of pokemon in your party. I fought two Panchamps of the same level. One time with 6 people and one time with 5 people. Everybody received the same amount of experience based on their participation independent of the amount of people in your party.

Comment: I added more labeled examples. The previous set did show all scenarios are once but I split them up better now.

Comment: Ah my last sentence was wrong. I fixed that too.

Comment: More information on [this post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135543/does-lucky-egg-boost-the-experience-gain-from-exp-share).

Comment: Say I have one sole pokemon battle participant with boosted experience due to affection, exp.share is turned on. Is the 50% calculated after the boost or before the boost?

Comment: @gitsitgo After. earthmeLon's link above should answer your question. Experience is split and then bonus items and trade/affection status is applied appropriately.